# How to call asp.net web service in android java?

Tags: android

Hi Everyone,
            How to call asp.net web service using android my web service is having fnsendsms(phoneno,message) on click of sendsms button i want to call fnsendsms function how to call that using java for that i have to download any jar files please help me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, download ksoap2 android jar. Then you can call web service like:

```
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(YOUR_CONNECTION_NAMESPACE, methodName);

            //add parameters to web service method..
        request.addProperty(parameterName, parameterValue);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(YOUR_CONNECTION_URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(YOUR_ACTION_NAME, envelope);

        result = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: I downloaded ksoap2 android jar files how to add these file resources to my project please help me?

Comment: Right click to your project folder in Eclipse. Click properties, then java build path > libraries > add external jar.

Comment: after that when i call envelope.response() it is giving following exception how to fix this org.ksoap2.SoapFault please help me

Comment: What is the exception? Please debug or look at the logCat.